# Как в Tomcat настроить заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: tomcat

Что сделать, что бы, tomcat выдавал такой заголовок

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tomcat версия 9, OC Windows

**UPD**

Html подгружает *GamePlatform.js* так

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://213.27.32.135:8080/games/mobile/platform/js/GamePlatform.jsv=1400771587"></script>
```

который подгружает *config.xml* так

```
function loadConfig()
{
    this.$error.hide();

    // TODO: config.xml should be removed and all settings for the game platform should
    // be taken from PlatformSettings.xml
    Loader.cacheTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    var configXMLLoader = new XMLLoader("config.xml");
    configXMLLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.COMPLETE, onConfigXMLLoaded, this);
    configXMLLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.ERROR, onConfigXMLError, this);
    configXMLLoader.load();
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://213.27.32.135:8080/games/mobile/config.xml?v=1499689563754. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://213.27.32.135' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Файлы находятся в Apache Tomcat. Как мне сделать что бы они подгружались?

Comment: у вас на сервер развернуто что-либо? что это за приложение? как оно развернуто?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman боюсь что я вас не понимаю(. У меня запущен мой сервер, программа на Делфи, слушает 80 порт, на нее идет первый запрос, в ответ высылаю html текст, далее эта html страничка подгружает файл GamePlatform.js уже делая запрос в Apache Tomcat 9, а в скриптах последнего есть подгрузка файла config.xml так же из Apache Tomcat 9

Comment: добавьте все это в вопрос. кто создает этот **config.xml**?

Comment: он не создается, он есть в "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT\games\mobile" его нужно только получить

Comment: как был создан ROOT?

Comment: я его просто скопировал в папку как и все ресурсы

Comment: откуда скопировали?

Comment: с интернета скачал

Comment: возможно вам не нужен tomcat и в принципе будет достаточно простого  http сервера. а почему вы не хотите отдавать эти файлы используя вашу программу на делфи?

Comment: не хочу нагружать сервер на делфи, а что за http сервер?

Comment: а вы ожидаете большое количество пользователей? думает ваш сервер не справится? http сервер apache или nginx.

Comment: ну а tomcat это не тоже самое, только apache  мне 80 порт занимает, я его на tomcat поменял

Comment: не тоже самое. tomcat - это сервер приложений. у apache можно настроить порт на котором он слушает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить фильтр в вашем **web.xml**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Вы можете передать дополнительные параметры фильтру. Почитать про них можно в [настройка фильтра CORS](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Comment: Я это читал, а куда этот фильтр вставлять, в нем нужно что нибудь менять?

Comment: в web.xml. если вас устраивают параметры по умолчанию, то ничего не надо настраивать.

Comment: Tomcat 9.0\conf\web.xml?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 который внутри war.

Comment: поиском по всей папке Tomcat 9.0 не нахожу war. Что это?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 war это то, что вы разворачиваете на сервер. Специальный архив с servlet и пр

Comment: @ArtGrek13 просто фильтр применяется на двух уровнях - глобальном и на уровне war.

Comment: Я честно говоря не понимаю о чем вы, у меня ошибка при запросе файла No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Вот здесь менять? ...\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager\WEB-INF\web.xml

Comment: @ArtGrek13 опишите в вопросе вашу проблему. Возможно дело не в CORS.

Comment: дополнил вопрос